# Run Laravel optimized and synched all the times

Tags: php, laravel, rsync, ubuntu-server

I am running my Laravel app on a very slow server, and running `php artisan optimize` makes a huge difference.

The obvious disadvantage: it does not react to file changes.

I need both:

- Quick response from a file change. The quickest is to `optimize:clear` right after something changed
- A fast loading application. Meaning, running `optimize`.

**MY SPEC** is an attempt of remote computing

- PHPStorm
- rsync -zar. Through SSH tunneling on change
- git is on my local machine on Windows (hate me)
- server is on ubuntu server

**THE STRAIGHTFORWARD SOLUTION**: create a watcher script that would watch for any file changes and:

- if file changed and the app is cached: run `optimize:clear`
- if a second has passed and there is no file changed then run `optimize`

**PROBLEMS**

- Sometimes e.g. on branch change there are 100 file changes and rsync updates every file one by one, thus this might trigger the script 100 unnecessary times
- Laravel is running on sail and for some reason everytime I run a command in the container, it takes 1-2 second to execute. Being inside the container fixes this delay.

Did someone attempted such a setup? Any suggestions?

Any other solutions/ideas are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Is that a production server? I am very confused, why do you need to optimize on every file change? If it is production, just do a normal deploy, and then run the command at the end. I do not understand your issue. If it is local development, why are you using this environment that way? something is off

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution would be to implement a cli script that is responsible for running a command and once the command is executed, then `optimize`, like

```
$(echo $1)
optimize
```

which executes the argument you passed and then optimizes it. If your script is called foo.sh, then you can run

```
bash foo.sh "git checkout somebranch"
```

This way, whatever command you want to run afterwards will be executed so.